# Difference between linux variables $BASH_SUBSHELL vs $SHLVL

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am confused between the two.

> While the $BASH_SUBSHELL internal variable indicates the nesting level of a subshell, the $SHLVL variable shows no change within a subshell.

What does it exactly mean? If i open a shell within another shell, the value of $SHLVL increments. Isn't that a subshell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, manually running a new shell (via `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` etc.) is *not* a subshell in this context.

A subshell is when the shell spawns a new shell instance *on its own* to handle some work.

Using [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) (i.e. `$(command)`) is a subshell (as is the older backticks invocation).

Using a [pipeline](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) (i.e. `echo '5.1+5.3' | bc -l`) creates subshells for each component of the pipeline.

Using [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (i.e. `<(command)`) creates a subshell.

[Grouping commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) (i.e. `(declare a=5; echo $a)`) creates a subshell.

Running commands in [the background](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) (i.e. `sleep 1 &`) creates a subshell.

There may be other things as well but those are the common cases.

Testing this is easy:

```
$ printf "Outside: $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL\nInside: $(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL)\n"
Outside: 0 , 1
Inside: 1 , 1
$ (printf "Outside: $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL\nInside: $(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL)\n")
Outside: 1 , 1
Inside: 2 , 1
$ bash -c 'printf "Outside: $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL\nInside: $(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL)\n"'
Outside: 0 , 2
Inside: 1 , 2
$ bash -c '(printf "Outside: $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL\nInside: $(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL , $SHLVL)\n")'
Outside: 1 , 2
Inside: 2 , 2
```

The source of your quote (the generally poor, and often better avoided, [ABS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)) even demonstrates this a little bit (and in a rather unclear manner, just another instance of the general lack of rigor and quality in that "Advanced" guide):

> ```
> echo " \$BASH_SUBSHELL outside subshell       = $BASH_SUBSHELL"           # 0
>   ( echo " \$BASH_SUBSHELL inside subshell        = $BASH_SUBSHELL" )     # 1
>   ( ( echo " \$BASH_SUBSHELL inside nested subshell = $BASH_SUBSHELL" ) ) # 2
> # ^ ^                           *** nested ***                        ^ ^
>
> echo
>
> echo " \$SHLVL outside subshell = $SHLVL"       # 3
> ( echo " \$SHLVL inside subshell  = $SHLVL" )   # 3 (No change!)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, It helped a lot.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Is ABS from TLDP, not a good source?  I had planned to read it? Should I skip for some better source? Could you please recommend?

Answer (score 11):

`$SHLVL:`
Shell level, how deeply Bash is nested. If, at the command-line, $SHLVL is 1, then in a script it will increment to 2. **This variable is not affected by subshells.**

`$BASH_SUBSHELL:`
A variable indicating the subshell level.

Here is how they will have different values:

```
# In the login bash shell
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL
0:1

# 1st nested child
bash
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL
0:2

# 2nd nested child
bash
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL
0:3

# back to 1st nested child
exit
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL
0:2

# back to parent shell
exit
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL
0:1

# first level sub-shell    
(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL)
1:1

# 2nd level sub-shell
( (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL) )
2:1

# 3rd level sub-shell
( ( (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL) ) )
3:1
```