# $SHLVL does not increase in ( echo $SHLVL)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am learning shell scripts and stuck at this little experimental shell scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
A=1
(A=2;echo "A is $A in $SHLVL")
echo "A is $A in $SHLVL"
exit 0
```

Without doubt, `$A` in line 3 and line 4 are different from each other, which can be explained that it is because the parent process cannot read variables created in the child process, that is, the subshell. However, the `$SHLVL` in line 3 and line 4 are the SAME, which I thought that `$A` in line 3 should have been bigger than `$A` in line 4 by 1. Didn't commands in line 3 executed in subshell? I don't know where I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to use `$BASH_SUBSHELL` instead of `$SHLVL` here.

`$BASH_SUBSHELL` is an internal variable that indicates the nesting level of a subshell.

Change your script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

A=1
(A=2;echo "A is $A in $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL")
echo "A is $A in $BASH_SUBSHELL:$SHLVL"
```

Now it will output:

```
A is 2 in 1:2
A is 1 in 0:2
```

You can see `$BASH_SUBSHELL` changes with the nesting level but `$SHLVL` remains same.

[Check this helpful answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799656/548225)

Comment: Thanks! Both your answers solved my questions. I am sorry I can only accept one solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hey but I answered 7 minutes before other answer :) and have more explanation.

Comment: @HanXIAO The accepted answer also seems like a duplicate to me. With a few minute delay...

Answer (score 0):

When you run a part of script in `()`, you generate subshell, where the code will be executed. 
But `$SHLVL` shows not that you expected, `$BASH_SUBSHELL` does.

`$SHLVL` indicates how many shells deep the user is.
When you just logged in via ssh on the server, it's usually `1`. If you run shell script, it would become `2`. `()` will create a subshell, but `$SHLVL` does not affected of subshells.

Instead, `$BASH_SUBSHELL` will show that you need - subshell level. And it will be changed, just check in your example.

```
$ cat shlvl.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
A=1
(A=2;echo "A is $A in $SHLVL" and  bash_subshell is $BASH_SUBSHELL)
echo "A is $A in $SHLVL ans bash_subshell is  $BASH_SUBSHELL"
exit 0
$ ./shlvl.sh 
A is 2 in 3 and bash_subshell is 1
A is 1 in 3 ans bash_subshell is  0
```